# prevent writing in a textbox if table length exceeded

Tags: jquery

so I'm using jquery tags input in my project i want to check if the user has entered more than the max allowed tags i should prevent him from writing how can i do that .
PS: i don't want to disable the input

that's my code so far :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tag1').tagsInput({
'width':'300px',
'height':'50px',
'minChars' : 1,
'maxChars' : 12,
'onAddTag':tagsCountExceeded

});

function tagsCountExceeded(){

var TagsCount=2;
var TagsTable=$('#tag1').val().split(",");

$('#tag1').keypress(function(e){
if(TagsTable.length==TagsCount)
e.preventDefault();
});

}

 });
</script>
```

but the keyPress function isn't working

Comment: The event is probably working just fine, but it won't stop your keyboard from working, or a regular input element from receiving those keys?

Comment: @Sora are u using any jquery plugin ?? what is tagsInput  ??

Comment: i am using jquery tags and yeah i can't manage to stop my keyboard from inserting more characters if the length is more than the max i want 2 prevent entering new characteres